# PropTypes receives undefined types in React-DND/Styled-Components combo

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-proptypes, react-dnd

I'm trying to get a small example of using `react-dnd` with `styled-components` and it works! However, it seems to have completely broken PropTypes.

[image: failed proptypes]

Which seems pretty strange to me. I have several working components with each and this worked before introducing `react-dnd`, so I'm baffled to say the least.

As mentioned, the code works as expected in browser and `console.log`ging the props and their types shows that they are indeed present and of valid type.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';

class StyleTest extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(Object.keys(props).map(p => (typeof props[p])));
    // prints ["string", "string", "function"]
  }

  render() {
    const { color, title, connectDragSource } = this.props;

    return (
      <Wrapper color={color}>
        <h1>HUZZAAAAH {title}</h1>
        <Button ref={instance => connectDragSource(instance)}>Make boring</Button>
        <CoolerButton>Make cool</CoolerButton>
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }

}

StyleTest.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
  connectDragSource: PropTypes.func
};

export default DragSource(
  'button_drag', 
  {
    beginDrag: () => {
      return {id: 42};
    }
  }, 
  (connect) => ({ 
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource()
  })
)(StyleTest);

let Wrapper = styled.div`
  height: 200px;
  background-color: peachpuff;

  h1 {
    color: ${props => props.color};
  }
`;

let Button = styled.div`
  width: 200px;

  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px 10px;

  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid grey;
`;

let CoolerButton = styled(Button)`
  border-color: orange;
  border-radius: 10px;
`;
```

Comment: Which version of React are you using?

Comment: 16.7.0 - Now the weird thing is that I cant replicate it in my other project, which uses the exact same React, Prop-Types, React-DnD and styled-components versions. Sorry for not investigating more thoroughly.